# How do I impove this small caching script

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am getting a list of product ID periodically, and I call these dynamic pages using `cfhttp` and save the received response as html file in root folder

my script may look like

```
<cfloop list="#productlist# index="productid" >
  <cfhttp url="//domainname.com" result="result" charset="utf-8"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="productid" value="#productid#"> 
  </cfhttp> 
  <cfset content = result.filecontent> 
  <cffile action="write" file="#filename#" output="#trim(content)#" /> 
</cfloop>
```

Is there any better or optimized way to achive this result?

Comment: You have shown us how you are creating the file but not how you are then using/reading that file. Can you include that code please? Be sure to include the portion of code where you determine whether to use the cached file or not. If you are just asking about this code snippet, then I don't see much to optimize. I would be careful of how many loop iterations it will be performing. That could make it a resource hog. If the domainname.com resource that you are calling is yours it would be better (faster) to make database calls instead of http calls. We need more information to help further.

Comment: You are probably not getting your desired results because your filename does not get changed inside your loop.

Comment: Did you know about `<cfcache>`? Because that's how you should do it in the first place.